# Do Visual Studio Database Project *.refactorlog Files Belong in Source Control?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012, version-control

I am using git (via GitHub for Windows) and I am using the [latest .gitignore for Visual Studio from GitHub](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore)

I notice that my `<ProjectName>.refactorlog` files are being included in my commits.

Do .refactorlog files belong in source control?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

The `.refactorlog` should be in source control if you intend to move database objects across schemas.

See: **MSDN:** [Move a Database Object to a Different Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193277%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

#### Relevant section: Preserving Your Intent With The Refactoring Log

> When you move a database object to a different schema, an entry is
>   added to the refactoring log for your database project. When you
>   deploy your changes, this log helps ensure that the corresponding
>   object in the target environment is renamed as you intended.
>   **Otherwise, the existing object would be dropped, and an object would be added with the new name**. The log is maintained in an XML file that
>   is named `ProjectName.refactorlog`. **You check this file in to version control when you check in the other files that compose your database project**. The `ProjectName.refactorlog` file contains only information
>   about refactoring operations that require special handling during
>   deployment.